# Python matplotlib uneven spacing y

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, ipython

I am wondering how the y axes has such behavior (uneven spacing) without specifying any thing regarding to the yscale as in the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


d=np.zeros([np.arange(0,8).shape[0],np.arange(0,100).shape[0]])

for i in np.arange(0,8):
    for j in np.arange(0,100):
        d[i,j]=(i+290)**2+j**2

c=np.array([1000,850,700,500,400,300,250,200])      

plt.contourf(np.arange(0,100),c,d);plt.colorbar()
plt.yticks(c,c[::-1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = np.zeros([np.arange(0, 8).shape[0], np.arange(0, 100).shape[0]])

for i in np.arange(0, 8):
    for j in np.arange(0, 100):
        d[i, j] = (i + 290) ** 2 + j ** 2
l = [1000, 850, 700, 500, 400, 300, 250, 200]
r = [l[-1] + l[0]-x for x in l]
c = np.array(l)
e = np.array(r)

plt.contourf(np.arange(0, 100), c, d)
plt.colorbar()
plt.yticks(e, c)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I understand this point, what I am asking about is what control the spacing, the y spacing is not linear, why ??

Comment: Do you want to change the scale?

Comment: Yes, I want to know why it behave like that without mentioning anything about the type of scale (linear, log, ..)

Comment: It behaves like this because you typed it in your code! Just use `plt.yticks(c,c)` without inverted labelling and you'll be happy.

Comment: @AhmedShaaban try with my solution

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing surprising about the outcome of that code. The only confusing thing for someone to look at this plot are the inverted labels on the y-axis. But since you have deliberately chosen to invert them, you shouldn't complain.

Here is an example which hopefully shows why it is very confusing to invert the axis labels..

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.array([0,1,5,10]) 
Z=np.zeros((len(y),len(x)))

for i in range(len(y)):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        Z[i,j]=i*j


fig, (ax, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3)

im = ax.contourf(x,y,Z)
ax.set_yticks(y)
ax.set_yticklabels(y[::-1])
ax.set_title("inverted labels")

im2 = ax2.contourf(x,y,Z)
ax2.set_yticks(y)
ax2.set_yticklabels(y)
ax2.set_title("normal labels")

im3 = ax3.contourf(x,y,Z)
ax3.set_yticks(y)
ax3.set_yticklabels("abcd")
ax3.set_title("letters as labels")

plt.show()
```

In the middle, the axis labels appear as one would expect them, on the left they are inverted. On the right we chose some non numeric labels
As one can see the scale is linear in all cases. In the case where we did not mess with the labels, this is clearly seen by the fact that on a scale from 0 to 10, 5 sits in the middle.

[image]